# ogg stream is not working on android chrome browser

Tags: html, video-streaming, android-webview, vlc, ogg

I am encoding camera stream to ogg an showing it on HTML5 app.
On Windows:-
chrome - showing green screen sometimes and sometimes streams shows up.
Mozilla - working fine

On android 
chrome - not working
Mozilla - Working fine 
WebView- not working, a big play button appears

**HTML code-**

```
<video  autoplay loop ><source type="video/ogg" src="streampath/name.ogg">
                                   </video>
```

**Vlc streaming code**

```
cvlc -vvv rtsp://cameraInputStream --sout '#transcode{vcodec=theo, vb=800, channels=1, ab=128, samplerate=44100, width=320}:http{dst=:8090/output.ogg}'
```

Why it is not working on android chrome browser ,android webview and green screen on windows chrome.